# Ordering a column with images

Tags: datatables

Will be posible to sort this image column?

Returning to my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgutbor/0566dbvv/), all I want is to sort this first column (Status) somehow.

```
Thanks in advance again.
```

Comment: do you want to sort the filter drop down element value? or the table column itself?

Comment: I want to sort the table column.

Comment: then it not related to yadcf, please edit your question/tags

Comment: Edited and waiting

Comment: Imo you need to provide more info/ code in the question itself and rely less on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Ordering in the datatables executed depending upon the text, that is present in the column. It doesn't take consideration whether any image is present or not.

You can try adding some alphabets or numbers to color codes, while keeping those texts hidden.

You can update your fiddle code as below in the html code, where you have placed images.

```
<td>
  <img src='http://lab.onclud.com/psm/blackcircle.png' class='black' />
  <label style="display: none;">1</label>
</td>

<td>
  <img src='http://lab.onclud.com/psm/redcircle.png' class='red' />
  <label style="display: none;">2</label>
</td>

<td>
  <img src='http://lab.onclud.com/psm/greencircle.png' class='green' />
  <label style="display: none;">4</label>
</td>

<td>
  <img src='http://lab.onclud.com/psm/yellowcircle.png' class='yellow' />
  <label style="display: none">3</label>
</td>
```